# "Constructor cannot be applied to given types" error

Tags: java, constructor, compiler-errors

I keep getting the errors:

```
3 errors found:
File: C:\Users\TUFRob\Documents\Computer Science II\Retail\RetailItemDemo.java  [line: 6]
Error: constructor RetailItem in class RetailItem cannot be applied to given types;
  required: int,double,java.lang.String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
File: C:\Users\TUFRob\Documents\Computer Science II\Retail\RetailItemDemo.java  [line: 7]
Error: constructor RetailItem in class RetailItem cannot be applied to given types;
  required: int,double,java.lang.String
  found: java.lang.String,int,double
  reason: actual argument java.lang.String cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion
File: C:\Users\TUFRob\Documents\Computer Science II\Retail\RetailItemDemo.java  [line: 8]
Error: constructor RetailItem in class RetailItem cannot be applied to given types;
  required: int,double,java.lang.String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

When I try to run my java program:

```
public class RetailItemDemo
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        RetailItem item1 = new RetailItem();
        RetailItem item2 = new RetailItem("Designer Jeans", 40, 34.95);
        RetailItem item3 = new RetailItem();
    }
}
```

with this class:

```
public class RetailItem
{
    private String description;
    private int unitsOnHand;
    private double price;

    public RetailItem(int unitsOnHand, double price, String description)
    {
        this.unitsOnHand = unitsOnHand;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble seeing what might be causing the error

Comment: Order of arguments is important.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor of RetailItem has input parameter like int, double and string. You should pass parameter value in order as per definition of it.  otherwise it will give `compile time error`. here you did same mistake.

**Problem 1:**

```
RetailItem item2 = new RetailItem(40, 34.95, "Designer Jeans");
```

instead of

```
RetailItem item2 = new RetailItem("Designer Jeans", 40, 34.95);
```

**Problem 2:**

```
RetailItem item3 = new RetailItem();
```

This syntax will try to call default constructor. In `RetailItem` class, you did not define default constructor as it will also give `compile time error`. Default constructor exist default only when no other constructor defined, otherwise you have to manually define it.

Refer: [what is constructor in java?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Comment: OP also needs to create empty constructor

Comment: I don't understand how i would go about solving problem 2

Comment: If you don't define a constructor in your `RetailItem` class, Java will create a no-arg one for you by default. But once you build your own, this default constructor is ***not*** provided to you. You must create your own, such as what bmthaker showed in `Problem 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RetailItem` has only one Constructor:

```
public RetailItem(int unitsOnHand, double price, String description){...}
```

Then, all of your call are wrong:

```
//Problem 1:  wrong because you have no constructor with no param
RetailItem item1 = new RetailItem();
RetailItem item3 = new RetailItem();
```

And

```
// Problem 2:
RetailItem item2 = new RetailItem("Designer Jeans", 40, 34.95);
//wrong because your Constructor is RetailItem(int, double, String)
// not RetailItem(String, int, double)
```

How to fix:

*Add default Constrcutor (no param) in you class to solve Problem 1*

```
public RetailItem(){
}
```

*To solve Problem 2, Change line 11 to:*

```
RetailItem item2 = new RetailItem( 40, 34.95,"Designer Jeans");
```